# Issue with Inject JS code to webview inside chrome OS app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app

I Created a Chrome OS APP to be a webview of my website, but I need to inject some JS codes to send some information to my server.
here the codes
**exported_app_view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="trim full">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foam.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cab.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application.css">
</head>
<script src="application.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<body class="trim full">
    <foam id="kiosk" model="AppConfig" view="KioskView">
 <webview id="map" src="http://link.com/">  </webview>

            </foam>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
core.appver = "1";
        }, 2000);
```

it is not working like this, but If inserted code like window.close(); it works well.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [addContentScripts](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-addContentScripts), look for examples around.

Comment: should I add it to main.js or inside application.js ?

Comment: now  I can see the functions in the debugger, but all of them are not defined, I already included jquery libs before my script